# I'm looking to mute someone in discord.js v13 and i have problem in creating VoiceState object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my first discord bot and I'm trying to mute someone. Based on my understanding I think I need to invoke the `[.setMute()][1]` function of the **[VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState)** and I'm trying to create a voiceState object where I dont understand what the data means.

Heres my execute function for the command. [ /mute <@USER> <SECONDS(optional)> ]

```
    async execute(interaction) {
    const targetUser = interaction.options.getUser('target');

    if (interaction.options.getNumber('seconds') !== null) {
        const seconds = interaction.options.getNumber('seconds');
    } else {
        const seconds = 60;
    }

    console.log(targetUser);
    
    const data = {} // APIVoiceState but idk what to put here
    const voiceState = new VoiceState(interaction.guild, data );
    console.log(voiceState);
    voiceState.selfMute(true);

    await interaction.reply('supposed to mute!');
```

Command Builder code if anyone needs it:

```
const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName('mute')
.setDescription('mute @user <seconds>  server mutes the specified user for specified number of seconds')
.addUserOption(option =>
    option.setName('target')
        .setDescription('user to mute')
        .setRequired(true))
.addNumberOption(option =>
    option.setName('seconds')
        .setDescription('Time in seconds the user stays muted (default: 60)'));
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a new `VoiceState` object, once a `GuildMember` joins a voice channel the API automatically offers the object, we just need to edit the `GuildMember`'s data using the [`GuildMemberEditData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/GuildMemberEditData) by passing the property `mute()` to it, so to utilize `GuildMemberEditData#mute()` method we can just go like:

```js
  const targetUser = interaction.options.getMember('target');
  targetUser.edit({mute : true})
```

Please note that you can only use it on a `GuildMember` object and not on an `User` object which you are getting `targetUser` as, I strongly recommend to edit that.

### Aliter

You can go ahead and get the `GuildMember`'s `voiceState` and use `setMute()` on that via the [`GuildMember#voice`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice) method then further use the [`VoiceState#setMute()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setMute) method on it, in that case our code would be something like this:

```js
 const targetUser = interaction.options.getMember('target');
 targetUser.voice.setMute(true);
```

Comment: Thank you calling getMember worked! 
also I learned that .edit() should be called like this:
targetUser.edit({mute: true})

Comment: No issues! Glad I was of help! If this answered your question, make sure to click the ✓ button so others who may visit this in future know it's the right solution and use the  button to get me and yourselves some reputation :D